# Help with Unit Testing

Tags: apex, unit-test

**Apex Class**

```
public class BytesToKbMbGbComponentController {

    public String controllerValue;

    public void setControllerValue (String s) {
        controllerValue = s.toUpperCase();
        Long longValue = Long.valueOf(s);

        if (longValue < 1024)
            controllerValue =  string.valueOf(longValue) + 'Bytes';
        else
            if (longValue >= 1024 && longValue < (1024*1024))
        {
            //KB
            Decimal kb = Decimal.valueOf(longValue);
            kb = kb.divide(1024,2);
            controllerValue = string.valueOf(kb) + 'KB';
        }
        else
            if (longValue >= (1024*1024) && longValue < (1024*1024*1024))
        {
            //MB
            Decimal mb = Decimal.valueOf(longValue);
            mb = mb.divide((1024*1024),2);
            controllerValue = string.valueOf(mb) + 'MB';
        }
        else
        {
            //GB
            Decimal gb = Decimal.valueOf(longValue);
            gb = gb.divide((1024*1024*1024),2);
            controllerValue = string.valueOf(gb) + 'GB';
        }
    }

    public String getControllerValue() {
        return controllerValue;
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class BytesToKbMbGbComponentControllerTest {
    public static testmethod void testsetControllerValue() {
        String controllerValue = '1932';
        System.assertEquals(controllerValue, '1932');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you've attempted so far?

Comment: hello Dan,@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class BytesToKbMbGbComponentControllerTest {
    
    public static testmethod void testsetControllerValue() {
        
        String controllerValue = '1932';
        System.assertEquals(controllerValue, '1932');
    }
}

Comment: i was new to these apex test classes so i am unable to write please help me out

Comment: this controller we used in a VF page where we can populate the values randomly on button click

Comment: First invest an hour of your own time by working through training material such as Trailhead's [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/apex_testing).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple class to cover. Clearly you're passing in a value in bytes that should set `controllerValue` to a more readable version.

What you want to do is call the `setControllerValue` function in your test method, passing in a value (e.g. 512) then asserting that `controllerValue` is equal to `512B`.

Let's look at your method so far:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class BytesToKbMbGbComponentControllerTest {
    public static testmethod void testsetControllerValue() {
        String controllerValue = '1932';
        System.assertEquals(controllerValue, '1932');
    }
}
```

- Firstly, don't use `(SeeAllData=true)`. This class is just processing values that gets supplied to it. It doesn't even use any `SOQL` or `DML`. You should almost never need to use this, it can slow things down massively and can cause massive headaches, believe me I've made this mistake... So we'll remove that.
- You're using public access modifers, really these should be private. As a rule of thumb, never give more access than you need to
- You're setting a String to the value of 1932, but you're never actually calling the method that's supposed to process it. How does Salesforce know what to execute? You've not told it anything.

Let's cover the first `if` statement, and you should be able to figure out the rest.

```
private class CallListContTest {
  @isTest static void test_bytes() {
    BytesToKbMbGbComponentController controller = new BytesToKbMbGbComponentController(); // Call the controller

    String bytes = '512'; // Set a "number" to process

    controller.setControllerValue(bytes); // Call the setControllerValue function, passing in the bytes variable we created earlier

    System.assertEquals('512Bytes', controller.getControllerValue()) // Assert the value. The function getControllerValue() returns a String so we can compare and cover this
  }
}
```

What you should see is everything covered up to the first `if` statement.

Why?

Because Salesforce is checking the value we pass in and finding that it meets the first criterea, so it's stops checking from there.

Next steps? Create 3 more methods that cover the other blocks depending on whether you expect KB, MB or GB.

**Other stuff**

- When this class is called, you're setting `controllerValue` to the value of the String entered (`controllerValue = s.toUpperCase();)`. Why? You're just going to overwrite it.
- You're doing a lot of preprocessing for something so simple. Try to avoid converting `String` to `Long` to `Decimal` to `String`. See if you can think of a way to avoid this.
- You really need to use error catching here. What happens if the `String` passed in looks like this: '512ABC'. What happens if I enter a negative value such as `-2048`? That doesn't look right does it?